# Have Current Page be Shown in Bold on Menu Bar

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How do I make it so when I click on a menu item and am taken to that page, the menu item is now in bold (or a different colour)?

For example, if I were to click on Product, when it loads to the /product page, I want "Product" on the menu to now be in bold.

I apologize if this is a simple task, I'm new to Vue and Nuxtjs.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline">
              <a
                href="/product"
                class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Product
              </a>
              <a
                href="/linkone"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Title One
              </a>
              <a
                href="/linktwo"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Title Two
              </a>
              <!--              <a-->
              <!--                href="/pricing"-->
              <!--                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"-->
              <!--                >Pricing-->
              <!--              </a>-->
              <a
                href="/about"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >About
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <!-- Mobile menu button -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
            id="main-menu"
            aria-label="Main menu"
            aria-haspopup="true"
          >
            <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
            <svg
              class="block h-6 w-6"
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
              />
            </svg>
            <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
            <svg
              class="hidden h-6 w-6"
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If you are using nuxtjs, why you did not use <nuxt-link> instead of <a>? It will be easy to <nuxt-link> and then walk throw the documentation and you will find an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be in your links do:

```
<a
    href="/product"
    class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
    :class="{ 'font-bold':(window.location.pathname === '/product') }"
>
    Product
</a>
```

All that is doing, is applying the `font-bold` class if the current pathname of the href matches the link. Hope that works for you!

*** Edit ***

I believe I forgot that `window` is not available in the template, but I believe route is, so you could use `$route.path` instead of `window.location.pathname`

Comment: if it's page template he can't use window object as the page template is rendered from the server, if it's a vue component he can use window. in the both cases it will be better to $route object instead of using window